# MS access 2007 use combobox to populate picture

Tags: combobox, ms-access-2007, image, autofill

**The question:**

What do i need to do so in my form I can use a comboBox and have it autofill a picture on both the form and table?

**The info:**

In Microsoft Access 2007, I have 1 table and 1 form. The table has all the info for name, phone, address, and picture and it all comes up right in the form. I have a ComboBox for com, fam1, fam2, and fam3, and when I select a name on the comboBox, it autofills the info on the table and form for the com, com phone,and com address, but not the picture. I'm thinking that I need to do some VB coding for the "on change" for the combobox. image 1 shows the format of the table. image 2 shows the format of the form.

[Picture1 http://dplcollagentherapy.com/pic01.JPG](http://dplcollagentherapy.com/pic01.JPG)

[Picture2 http://dplcollagentherapy.com/pic02.JPG](http://dplcollagentherapy.com/pic02.JPG)

Comment: On your form layout I see a control that corresponds to each field in your table. That makes sense. What I *don't* see is why any of those pictures should change (unless you navigate to another record in the table). Say you pick a new value from the `Com` combo box. That will change the value in the `Com` field for that record in the table, but it would have no effect on the `[com picture]` field. Is there some other background processing taking place that you forgot to mention?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to update the com phone and the com address with the following code. but the comboBox didn't let me add the picture into column 3 which would have made this so much easier. I will at some point make a report and it might be easier to have the report do a lookup for the picture. not sure what coding i would to for the lookup though. Thank you again. 
**The code**

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Combo30_Change()
Me.txtcomphone.Value = Me.Combo30.Column(1)
Me.txtcomaddress.Value = Me.Combo30.Column(2)
Me.com_picture = dlookup("name", "Elders", "Name=" & Com)
End Sub

Private Sub Combo32_Change()
Me.txtfam1phone.Value = Me.Combo32.Column(1)
Me.txtfam1address.Value = Me.Combo32.Column(2)
End Sub

Private Sub Combo48_Change()
Me.txtfam2phone.Value = Me.Combo48.Column(1)
Me.txtfam2address.Value = Me.Combo48.Column(2)
End Sub

Private Sub Combo56_Change()
Me.txtfam3phone.Value = Me.Combo56.Column(1)
Me.txtfam3address.Value = Me.Combo56.Column(2)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is not putting the actual images in the table, but placing them all on the form itself.  Assign each picture its own unique name that corresponds to the field it's associated with.  Each picture is set to invisible.  Then in VBA you can write a code like this:

```
If Me.ComboBox = Name Then
Me.NamesPicture.Visible = True
Else
Me.NamesPicture.Visible = False
End If
```

You can stack all the pictures on top of each other and the VBA runs very smoothly, I've used it in the past for small projects at work.  Hopefully this helps a little! :)